# calling service from c++ code. /gazebo/set_model_state

Tags: gazebo, c++, service, simulator-gazebo, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to call the service /gazebo/set_model_state from gazebo package. I can do it by command-console:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/set_model_state '{model_state: { model_name: my_robot, pose: { position: { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 ,z: 0.1 }, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0 } }, twist: { linear: {x: 0.0 , y: 0 ,z: 0 } , angular: { x: 0.0 , y: 0 , z: 0.0 } } , reference_frame: world } }'
```

i tryed to do this in c++ code. someone can say me what is wrong? this is the code:

```
#include "gazebo/SetModelState.h"

...

        geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose;
        start_pose.position.x = 0.0;
        start_pose.position.y = 0.0;
        start_pose.position.z = 2;
        start_pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
        start_pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
        start_pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
        start_pose.orientation.w = 0.0;

        geometry_msgs::Twist start_twist;
        start_twist.linear.x = 0.0;
        start_twist.linear.y = 0.0;
        start_twist.linear.z = 0.0;
        start_twist.angular.x = 0.0;
        start_twist.angular.y = 0.0;
        start_twist.angular.z = 0.0;

        gazebo::ModelState modelstate;
        modelstate.model_name = (std::string) "robovolc";
        modelstate.reference_frame = (std::string) "world";
        modelstate.pose = start_pose;
        modelstate.twist = start_twist;

        ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo::SetModelState>("/gazebo/set_model_state");
        //ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo::SetModelState>("/gazebo/SetModelState");

        gazebo::SetModelState setmodelstate;
        setmodelstate.request.model_state = modelstate;
        client.call(setmodelstate);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12931/calling-service-from-c++-code.-/gazebo/set_model_state/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i solved the problem!
the line

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
```

wasn't visible for the call to node. i rewrote it close to the code.

---

Originally posted by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) with karma: 155 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Please see here for a similar question/answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/3905/gazebo-service-through-c-code).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1